# Preventing the action tag from switching the current page?

Tags: php, html

I currently have two PHP files set up, one that functions as the form and the other that functions as the processor of the information provided. They are linked together like so:

```
<form action="processing.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When I hit submit, the page switches to the 'processing.php' file. I recently implemented required fields that users must enter, but they cannot see this warning because the page switches. I am testing this in WAMP.

I think a solution may be to include the processing script in the same file as the actual form, but the script is pretty long and I'd really like it to stay in two separate files for readability.

Is there a way that I can prevent the page from switching to the page indicated in the action tag?

Comment: How did you implement the required fields? With a Javascript validation script? It should call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the submission from happening if the user didn't enter the required fields.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't do this, I was thinking I would only need PHP. Would I have to make a new file to use Javascript or would it be parsed properly in a PHP file? Using PHP for required fields isn't probably the best idea anyway because it still submits the data, it just notifies that they need to fill a certain field out.

Comment: PHP can output anything into the HTML file, including Javascript and CSS. PHP doesn't run until you submit the form, so it's too late to prevent it from going to the new page.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? Do you mean it is too late for me to use Javascript to require some fields?

Comment: No, it's too late to use PHP. PHP runs AFTER the form is submitted, so it can't prevent submission. Javascript runs in the browser, so it can prevent submission.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how web browsers and servers interact with each other. You can't write web applications if you don't understand the basics.

Comment: You can always `include` the processing code inside the form page, if you want to keep them "separate".

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I will dedicate some time to learning more about the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP POST from a form goes to whatever form action you set.  If you want logic applied that's in a different file, you need to restructure things so that your logic is in processing.php, or you need to change the form action.

If you want to prevent page refresh all together, you need to use ajax.

Comment: What if I included the whole script within one file? I know it is probably a bad practice and I shouldn't do that though.

Is it still considered a page refresh if the page goes from "localhost/applicaiton.php" to "localhost/processing.php"?

Comment: If the page changes, I would call that a refresh / reload / etc.  The user sees white space and then more content loads.  You don't have to include the whole script in one file, but when you do a POST from a form, if you have an action attribute, that's where the browser sends the request.  There's nothing wrong with including the whole script in one file.  Just check for !empty($_POST) and you know the form has been submitted.

Comment: If I did include it in one file, would I just not have an action then?

Comment: Let's say form is generated in myform.php.  You can also set the action to myform.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to prevent the page switch if the required fields aren't properly filled, you need to create an onSubmit javascript call, then return false if field validation fails.